# RXJS Encrypting large files and sending to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, rxjs, aes

I am relatively new to RXJS and its a pretty steep learning curve. I am streaming files over GRPC and i want to encrypt them with AES then store them in an S3 bucket. Currently i am storing buffers in memory which is going to become an issue real quick if i start uploading large files.

I am wondering how i can consume RXJS stream, pipe it through encryption then pipe it to S3 bucket (i.e i do not want to store the whole file in memory)

Is this even possible or am i misunderstanding something?

Here is my current implmentation

```
  @GrpcStreamMethod()
  upload(data$: Observable<FileUploadRequest>): Observable<FileUploadResponse> {
    let fileBuffer: Buffer;
    let metaBuffer: Buffer;
    let storageBucket: string;
    let publicKey: string;
    let publicKeyHash: string;

    const response$ = new Subject<FileUploadResponse>();
    let headersDeliverd = false;

    const symetricKeys = this.service.generateEncryptionKeys(); //returns key + iv
    const fileCipher = this.service.getCypher(symetricKeys); //returns cipher
    const metaCipher = this.service.getCypher(symetricKeys); //returns cipher

    data$.subscribe({
      next: (data: FileUploadRequest) => {
        const content = data?.file?.content;
        const meta: Meta = data?.metadata;

        // Metadata has been delivered
        if (meta && !headersDeliverd) {
          headersDeliverd = true;

          publicKey = meta.owner;
          publicKeyHash = this.service.createHash(meta.owner);
          storageBucket = join(FILE_STORE, publicKeyHash);
          const metaBuff = this.service.metaToBuffer(meta);
          metaBuffer = metaCipher.update(metaBuff);
        }

        if (content && !headersDeliverd) {
          console.log('SOME ERROR');
        }

        if (content && headersDeliverd) {
          fileBuffer = fileCipher.update(content);
        }
      },
      complete: async () => {
        const encryptedSymetricKey = await this.service.encryptSymetricKey(
          symetricKeys,
          publicKey,
        );

        fileBuffer = Buffer.concat([fileBuffer, fileCipher.final()]);
        metaBuffer = Buffer.concat([metaBuffer, metaCipher.final()]);

        const documentId = uuidv4();
        const fileName = `${documentId}.file`;
        const metaName = `${documentId}.meta`;
        const keys = `${documentId}.access`;

        await this.service.uploadToAws(
          metaBuffer,
          `${publicKeyHash}/${metaName}`,
        );
        await this.service.uploadToAws(
          fileBuffer,
          `${publicKeyHash}/${fileName}`,
        );
        await this.service.uploadToAws(
          JSON.stringify({
            [publicKeyHash]: encryptedSymetricKey,
          }),
          `${publicKeyHash}/${keys}`,
        );

        response$.next({
          status: Status.SUCCESS,
          path: storageBucket,
        });
        return response$.complete();
      },
    });

    return response$.asObservable();
  }
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't use Node.js streams, which play well with crypto? The return value of crypto.createCipheriv() is a Stream.Transform, for example. You can basically pipe the file in, through, and out to S3 directly. RxJS sounds like an impediment here.

Comment: Your correct it is an impediment. The only real reason i'm using RXJS here is because the framework i'm using uses RXJS to deal with GRPC streams https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/grpc#grpc-streaming would you suggest i figure out how to come away from using RXJS?

Comment: I have come up with a solution that i will post here when i have completed it. essntially i just create a read stream and push the chunks to the stream, i can then pipe it through enncryption and then to aws. Achived it like so `next: (data: FileUploadRequest) => readableStream.push('data')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i cam up with was to just create a stream and push the data too it.

```
uploadToAws(key) {
    const pass = new PassThrough();

    return {
      writeStream: pass,
      promise: this.s3.send(
        new PutObjectCommand({
          Bucket: '...',
          Key: key,
          Body: pass,
          ServerSideEncryption: '...',
          ContentLength: 37, //If you do not put content lendth will error
        }),
      ),
    };
}

const stream = new Readable({
  read(data) {
    return data;
  },
});

data$.subscribe({
    next: (data) => stream.push(data),
    error: (error) => stream.destroy(),
    complete: async () => stream.destroy()
});

stream.pipe(encryptFunc).pipe(uploadToAws);
```